Не работает Демонстрация в Discord на Linux Debian 13 plasma
недавно перешел на Debian. Не работает демонстрация вообще. При попытке разрешить дискорду захватить мой экран/приложение. Вылетает ошибка "failed to connect pipewire context". Использую Debian 13 с оболочкой plasma. Искал решение в интеренете ничего нет, что помогло бы. Помогите товарищи прошу, очень нужна помощь.

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Нужна помощь по настройке Linux и починки демонстрации экрана
